# Choosing parameter in PHP

Tags: php

```
$n = 3;

function derde_macht($n) {
    return pow($n, 3);
}

 {
    echo $n . "x" . $n . "x" . $n . "=" . derde_macht(3);
}
```

How could I make this so that you can choose a parameter for `$n = 3;`?

Comment: when you want to choose parameter ? ... need more clarification what you want to achieve.

Comment: When you choose 10 as parameter for example it should show 10x10x10=1000 because when I change $n = 3; to 10 the code wont work

Answer (score 0):

Got this :

**derde_macht($n) you need to pass your $n in that function instead of derde_macht(3).**

```
$n = 10;

function derde_macht($n) {
    return pow($n, 3);
}

 {
    echo $n . "x" . $n . "x" . $n . "=" . derde_macht($n);
}
```